# Two Generic List in one Type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics

I would like to style generic variables with XAML.
For that I need `{x:Type myTypes:theType}`.

So I have:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    //
}

public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    //
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    //
}

public class ListA : List<ClassA>
{
    //
}

public class ListB : List<ClassB>
{
    //
}
```

Is it possible that I create a class that can be eather ListA or ListB?

I would need to use it for a DataTemplate with TargetType and I would like to make just one Template for ListA and ListB without a TemplateSelector.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could implement common functionality as an interface.

In this example, I modified your `ListA` and `ListB` to expose a common interface. I'll admit that I do not know WPF that well, but this would allow you to use common methods in either a `ListA` or `ListB` instance.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string BaseClassFoo { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public string ClassAFoo { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public string ClassBFoo { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyList {
    void CommonOperation();
}

public class ListA : List<ClassA>, IMyList
{
    public void CommonOperation() {
        Console.WriteLine(this[0].ClassAFoo);
    }
}

public class ListB : List<ClassB>, IMyList
{
    //
    public void CommonOperation() {
        Console.WriteLine(this[0].ClassBFoo);
    }
}

class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        IMyList a = new ListA { new ClassA { ClassAFoo = "I'm an A" } };
        IMyList b = new ListB { new ClassB { ClassBFoo = "I'm a B" } };

        a.CommonOperation();
        b.CommonOperation();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm an A
I'm a B
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Something like this?

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };

ICollection ListC = listA;

ListC = listB;
```